# QueryDsl aggregate by day of week as map

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I would like to get the number of bookings by type by day of week, e.g.:

```
| DoW   | Type   | Count |
|-----  |--------|-------|
| 1     | Store  | 3     |
| 1     | Remove | 2     |
```

Result should be `Map<Integer, Map<String, Long>>`. I've tried this in some variations:

```
LocalDateTime monday = LocalDate.now().with(DayOfWeek.MONDAY).atStartOfDay();
LocalDateTime nextMonday = monday.plusDays(7);

var dayOfWeek = booking.bookingDate.dayOfWeek().subtract(1);

new JPAQuery<>(entityManager)
                .select(dayOfWeek, booking.bookingType, booking.bookingType.count())
                .from(booking)
                .where(booking.bookingDate.between(monday, nextMonday))
                .groupBy(booking.bookingDate, booking.bookingType)
                .transform(groupBy(dayOfWeek)
                        .as(map(booking.bookingType, booking.bookingType.count())));
```

It doesn't give me the correct counts though (everything 1). I thought about putting `dayofweek` in the groupby clause, bc. I was worried that grouping by LocalDateTime, the "time" part would mess things up, but that didn't work.

This postgresql query works as expected:

```
select
    extract(DOW from b.book_date)-1 as dow,
    b.dtype as type,
    count(b.dtype) as cnt 
from
    booking b 
where
    b.book_date between '2020-05-11 0:0:0.000000' and '2020-05-18 0:0:0.000000'
group by
    b.book_date,
    b.dtype
```

**EDIT:**

When adding "dayOfWeek" to the groupBy clause, like this:

```
.groupBy(dayOfWeek, buchung.buchungType)
```

Then I get an Exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
[...]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Feld 

"BOOKING0_.BOOKING_DATE" muss in der GROUP BY Liste sein
Column "BOOKING0_.BOOKING_DATE" must be in the GROUP BY list; SQL statement:
/* select dayofweek(booking.gebuchtDate) - ?1, booking.bookingType, count(booking.bookingType)
from Buchung booking
where booking.bookingDate between ?2 and ?3
group by dayofweek(booking.gebuchtDate) - ?1, booking.bookingType */ select dayofweek(booking0_.booking_date)-? as col_0_0_, booking0_.dtype as col_1_0_, count(booking0_.dtype) as col_2_0_ from booking booking0_ where booking0_.booking_date between ? and ? group by dayofweek(booking0_.booking_date)-? , booking0_.dtype [90016-200]
```

**EDIT 2:**

Jan-Willem Gmelig Meyling's answer below fixes the query, but my logic to convert Day of Week from Sun-Sat to Mon-Sun is of course rubbish. Let's have a look:

[Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) will return Sunday (0) to Saturday (6) (which seems to be the ISO SQL way), whereas [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) returns ISO-8601 standard format from Monday (1) to Sunday (7). So basically everything matches up, except for Sunday. 
To make matters worse, I've read that you can change the start day of the week on MS SQL.

Since I don't want to bother with this headache, I've changed it to Day of Year and I'm converting in Java. Since the result set has at most 7 entries, this isn't so bad:

```
    var dayOfYear = booking.bookingDate.dayOfYear();
    
    var res = new JPAQuery<>(entityManager)
            .from(booking)
            .where(booking.bookingDate.between(monday, nextMonday))
            .groupBy(dayOfYear, booking.bookingType)
            .transform(groupBy(dayOfYear)
                    .as(map(booking.bookingType, booking.bookingType.count())));

    return res.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(toMap(
                    e -> Year.now().atDay(e.getKey()).getDayOfWeek().getValue(),
                    Map.Entry::getValue
            ));
```

Comment: You'll have to group by `dayOfWeek`, as grouping by `booking.bookingDate` effectively groups by day-of-year. As a rule of thumb: you need to group by any non-aggregate expression in your projection (in this case the transformation of the factory expression).

What exactly isn't working still when you group by `dayOfWeek` instead of `booking.bookingDate` (very important to not group by them both FWIW).

Comment: I've ammended my question

Comment: The "1" is parameterized, and as a result the group by expression is not "equal" from the select expression at query execution planning time. You have to use a constant for 1. I.e. `.subtact(Expressions.numberTemplate("1"))`.

Furthermore, I believe QueryDSL adds 1 to DayOfWeek for it to be consistent with Java's Day of Week rather than the DayOfWeek defined in ANSI SQL. You could consider using a custom instance of `JPQLTemplates` that defines a different standard template for the `DAY_OF_WEEK` operator (and renders the constant there). This can than be a safer default in your application.

Comment: Alternatively, when using Hibernate 5.4.10 or newer, you can also use "group by alias": use `dayOfWeek.as("dayOfWeekAlias")` in your select expression, and then use `Expressions.numberPath("dayOfWeekAlias")` in your group by clause :) Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "1" is parameterized, and as a result the group by expression is not "equal" from the select expression at query execution planning time. You have to use a constant for 1. I.e. `.subtact(Expressions.numberTemplate(Integer.class, "1"))`.

Furthermore, I believe QueryDSL adds 1 to DayOfWeek for it to be consistent with Java's Day of Week rather than the DayOfWeek defined in ANSI SQL. You could consider using a custom instance of `JPQLTemplates` that defines a different standard template for the `DAY_OF_WEEK` operator (and renders the constant there). This can than be a safer default in your application.

Alternatively, when using Hibernate 5.4.10 or newer, you can also use "group by alias": use `dayOfWeek.as("dayOfWeekAlias")` in your select expression, and then use `Expressions.numberPath(Integer.class, "dayOfWeekAlias")` in your group by clause:

```
new JPAQuery<>(entityManager)
        .from(booking)
        .where(booking.bookingDate.between(monday, nextMonday))
        .groupBy(Expressions.numberPath(Integer.class, "dayOfWeekAlias"), booking.bookingType)
        .transform(groupBy(dayOfWeek).as("dayOfWeekAlias")
            .as(map(booking.bookingType, booking.bookingType.count())));
```

Comment: Ty, great observation. FYI, a Type arg is needed: `Expressions.numberTemplate(Integer.class, "1")`. I tested it before and no, first day of week is not equal to Java's. I'm not familiar with `JPQLTemplates `. I'm using v5.4.20, but what you suggested did not work. It tried to acces "dayOfWeekAlias" as property and did not generate an alias.

Comment: The select is overwitten by the transform. Select is unnecessary here. Did you use the “.as(...)” call in .select or in the transform section?

Comment: Interesting. So I removed the `select` and put `dayOfWeek.as("dow1")` in the `groupBy` clause, then `.transform(groupBy(Expressions.numberPath(Integer.class, "dow1"))` but I get a `QuerySyntaxException`.
I also just realized that my day of week translation is rubbish...

Comment: It has to be the other way around: group by can reference an alias in the select clause, the latter is in your case is defined by your transform projection. Almost there!

Comment: There we go! It worked. I'll fill in some of the details in the question and answer, if that's alright with you.

Comment: Go ahead! Wanted to update it as well, but didnt get to it yet.